# Page content in CMS doesn't reflect live page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cms

I've inherited a project from another dev. I'm trying to make a small edit to a static page that he's set up through CMS>Pages in the admin. Strangely, the content that is displayed on the actual page is different than what I see in the admin. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: If there is no dynamic content being created on the client with e.g. jQuery, I would first alter the layout file associated with the CMS page, and check the result.

Comment: Also possible that the TinyMCE editor (the WYSIWYG editor used by Magento) is stripping out certain tags. Things like script tags, iframe tags, style tags (and some others I believe) will get removed once you save the CMS page.

Comment: If you're using version control you'll need to click "publish" on the content for it to display live.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct CMS page? There could be more than one CMS page with the same identifier, on different store views. Also there could be a custom Router in a module that might respond to the URL you are viewing.

Answer (score 1):

- Flush all Magento Cache
- Flush your browser cache
- Ensure that if you are running a multi-store / language site that you are looking at the correct page.
  [image]
- Try creating a separate CMS page and see if you can access that one.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times.

One of these worked:

-Log out, back in
-Clear Magento Cache
-Re-index data